Require minimal length of key in query params with .htaccess
The keys of query params of URLs should have a minimal length, e.g. 6 characters, to be accepted. This should be filtered by .htaccess.
Example of URL being ok:
https://example.com/blogs/?thisisalongkey=134234
Example of URL having a too short key - should be stopped: https://example.com/blogs/?shkey=134234
Is it possible to check the length of a key only?
I've tried this in .htaccess but it didn't work, also long keys were "bad" ones and stopped.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[a-z][a-z0-9]{1,5} [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]


A check in client side code?

And "it didn't work" means what exactly ? What happened when you made a test request? How did you make sure that distributed configuration files are considered at all by the apache http server? Where exactly did you implement that rule? What else do you have inside your configuration file? And ... by the way ... that rule would match all keys with a legth between 1 and 6, which probably is not what you want. Please add more details to the question.

The .htaccess is set into the root directory of the website.
The lines shown above are right under "RewriteEngine on" and two lines to redirect http requests to https.
I tested with the two URLs shown in the question, only the hostname was replaced by the hostname of my test site.
The "being ok" URL showed a page of the blog.
The "too short" URL should return a 403 as the key is only 5 characters long - but didn't.

Fine that you were able to solve your issue. A hint for future questions. There is an "edit" button below your question. Use that to "add more details to the question" next time. Thanks ;-)

Ok, searching for regex and "limiting string length" helped to find a regex pattern for checking if the length is in a set range.
And checking the length of the key only requires to split key and value, separated by a =.
These .htaccess lines work = a 403 is returned if ...

the length-to-be-checked key is the 1st parameter
only \w characters are in the key
this key is 1 to 5 characters long

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(\w{1,5})=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

